# Showing div layer with GWT

Tags: java, javascript, gwt

I have a div element defined in a html page, and through GWT i am trying to access it, but as of right now i havent managed to.

The usage for this div it is to show a loading type gif screen while the app completes some RPC stuff.

The code i am using is :

```
<div class="loadingMessage" align="center">    
    <div class="popupEsperaImagen">
        <img src="progreso.gif" width="10%" height="10%" id="ImagenEspera"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

And:

```
    public static void showLoadingBanner(){
        DOM.getElementById("loadingMessage").getStyle().setDisplay(Display.BLOCK);
    }

    public static void hideLoadingBanner(){
        DOM.getElementById("loadingMessage").getStyle().setDisplay(Display.NONE);
    }
```

When i debug the app, inspecting DOM.getElementById("loadingMessage") returns a null.

I have looked around in stackoverflow forums, but havent found any suitable solution yet.

Could you please give me some light on what i can be missing?.

Thank you in advance for your time,

Kind regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dom.getElementById will get an element by it's id field not it's class field. You need to add an id for the div element.

```
<div id="loadingMessage" class="loadingMessage" align="center">
```

Answer (score -1):

Regarding the visibility of the item in GWT this was the solution i got to from the response by Chris Hinshaw:

To show the div :

```
DOM.getElementById("loadingMessage").getStyle().setVisibility(Visibility.VISIBLE);
```

To hide the div:

```
DOM.getElementById("loadingMessage").getStyle().setVisibility(Visibility.HIDDEN);
```

Using the solution above proposed.